# jupgrade-joomla upgrade from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, upgrade

Long time back I used jUpgrade plugin for joomla upgrade.
But now the plugin / component is not in use to upgrade the joomla version from 1.5 to 2.5

Is there any other freeware plugin for migration?

I used following components.
Gavick Pro
Jcomments
jcraweler
jfusion
Joomfish and
 
k2

Pleas give some suggesstions to upgrade the joomla from 1.5 to 2.5

Answer (score 2):

jUpgrade has been unpublished due to a broken download link, however things have changed on their official website and it can still be downloaded:

http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/jupgrade

I forgot to mention that jUpgrade does not upgrade your 3rd party extensions such as JEvents. You will have to download the Joomla 2.5 compatible version for each one unfortunately. The same goes for the site template.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Theme, menus, user content are updated. But the menu linked to component are not working. The error message displayed in the menu is "Component 'com_jevents' does not exist", "Component 'com_adsmanager' does not exist", Component 'com_youtubegallery' does not exist, etc.. BUT their datas / tables are sucessfully moved to latest vesion's table. Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: please refer this link for the issue in menu page - [link](http://115.112.70.158/jupgrade/menus_issue.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but things have changed on redComponent again. They now don't have an installer available on the site.

However, if redMigrator (the JUpgrade replacement) doesn't meet your needs (as in my particular case, today), they have put the JUpgrade source on GitHub

https://github.com/fastslack/jUpgrade

Just clone the repo down and then run releases/make_release.sh

Answer (score 0):

http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/jupgrade

It's still available from the makers website. Just been unpublished on JED for some reason. Keep on using it as before as far as I'm concerned.

There are no other well recognized freeware upgrades just the paid [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609) (note the support on this extension as it is a paid extension is much better however for a generic upgrade stick with jUpgrade). However free upgrades do exist and can be found under [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion) section on JED.